# Storage Resource provider limits are per subscription or per storage account?

Tags: azure

As mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#storage-resource-provider-limits
Are the storage resource provider limits at per subscription or per storage account level?

Answer (score 0):

These limits are per subscription and not per storage account. Other limits like Azure Blob storage limits etc. are per storage account.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#storage-limits for all details

Comment: @LMG - This is what OP included in the question :).